# circular file references are not allowed error

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, variations

Recently we disabled automatic replication to the different variations of a publishing page when you publish using the following instructions with PowerShell:

```
   $site = Get-SPSite "<SiteURL>"
   $folder = $site.RootWeb.Lists["Relationships List"].RootFolder
   $folder.Properties.Add("DisableAutomaticPropagation", $true)
   $folder.Update()
   $site.Close()
```

(Source: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/sharepoint-variations-guide-part-2.html)

We have done it in diffent environments. In the firsts environments there was no problem and now is working as expected. But in the last environment we have applied this, we have the problem when we want to create the pages in the corresponding variations using the Update button. The pages are created but apparently trying to access them we get the error "circular file references are not allowed".

If instead of using the update button, I use the Create button, pages are created correctly.

Have you any clue what may be happening and how to fix?

Thank you very much.